# Woocommerce - Items with a quantity of 0 are added to the cart?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have item quantities on the shop page next to each item. The user can enter their quantity and click the add to cart button, which will add the item to the cart using ajax. By default I have the item quantity set to 0; however if the user clicks the add to cart button when the quantity is 0, the item will be added to the cart with a quantity of 1.

**What I want to happen** is if the item quantity is 0 then a message will appear telling the user to enter their quantity and the item will not be added to the cart.

Is this possible? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the benefit of having a 0 quantity item in the cart. It just seems like you are making it more difficult on yourself and not improving the customer experience.

Comment: I completely agree. However it's not my decision - even after explaining this. I need to get this working, but have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: You mean you have no idea how to *break* it. Wrongheaded and stubborn clients, I presume. See [here](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-cart.php#L885-L887) for where adding a 0 quantity to the cart will throw an error. And [here](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-cart.php#L1041) for how the item is removed from the cart when the quantity is set to 0. Short of hacking the `WC_Cart` class directly, I see no "solution" here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, add This  to  your custom JS code.

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".woocommerce div.product form.cart .button").click(function(){
    if(jQuery('input[name="quantity"]').val() == 0 || 'input[name="quantity"]').val() == ""){
       alert("Quantity should be at least 1. The item will not be added to cart.");
       return false;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you It works! One problem; the page has several quantity input fields for different products, so doesn't quite work unless all the inputs are more than 0. I've tried adding this $(this).prevAll('input[name="quantity"]').val() but I got the error message "$ is not a function". Any suggestions?

Comment: Instead of "$" , write "jQuery"